# iPad - Portrait and Landscape - Calculate how much angle it made with my desk

Tags: ipad, measurement, angle

I'm creating an app for iPad that works both in landscape and portrait mode.
I want to place one edge of iPad on my desk and slant(angle) it.
Now I want to measure how much angle it made with my desk. 
Using accelerometer, I'm getting X,Y and Z values. But I couldn't find how to convert those values into degrees.
Any way to convert XYZ to degrees?

Answer (score 0):

X, Y and Z force values give you the acceleration in each of these three directions.

You need to combine these to work out the net acceleration and it's angle.  This is just a problem of high school geometry.

[image]

Just considering the Z and Y accelerometers for the moment, when the iPad is at an angle, the accelerometers will also be at an angle with respect to the direction of gravity.  If we can work out the direction of gravity, we can work out the inclination to the ground (table).

```
 ø = atan(y/z)
```

Assuming your iPad is resting on one edge, either `x` or `y` should be approximately zero, and the other will be the value to use for y in the calculation above.

if x and y are approximately zero, the iPad is flat on the table.

Comment: Do I've to take the absolute value of Y & Z (Because sometimes i'm seeing that Y & Z are -ve values sometimes). Is this formula for portrait or landscape mode? Are y & z that you are representing the accelerometer values?

Comment: You should not need to take the absolute value, but I don't know if the iPad flat on the desk has -ve or +ve Z.  Give it a try!  I don't know which axis is Y on the ipad (long or short axis) but a little experimentation should tell you quickly.  There are accelerometer apps on the iTunes store that will give you this data.